# How do I make a command that checks for a message (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm here with a question. I made this command that pings someone but I don't know how to make it stop. Originally it would listen for "~stop" and it would break the message sending loop. It wouldn't work though. Please help!

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx, member:discord.User=None):
  pingEvent = 0
  if (member == None):
    await ctx.send("who do you want me to ping stupid")
  if "~stop" in ctx.channel
    pingEvent = 0
  else:
    pingEvent = 1
    while pingEvent <= 1:
      await ctx.send(
        f"{member.mention}"
      )
      if pingEvent == 0:
        break
```

Comment: This looks like you're just trying to spam, which is in violation of the ToS and will get your bot ratelimited if not banned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick and might look more simple than the answer above/below

```py
def check(m):
    return ctx.channel == m.channel and m.author == ctx.author
try:
    message = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=300)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send("You've used too long to answer!")
else:
   return
```

Comment: This will send `You've used too long to answer!` every time after the ping if we put it in a for loop, and since the timeout is 300, it will ping once in 300 seconds, which I think is not what OP wants

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your bot will get rate limited and eventually banned for doing this, but for educational purposes. Here is the solution.

**Checking for stop inside loop**

```py
for _ in range(20): #restrict pings to avoid being banned
   await ctx.send(member.mention)

   try: 
      msg = await client.wait_for("message", check= lambda x: x.author == ctx.author and x.content.contains('~stop'), timeout=2)
   except asyncio.TimeoutError:
      continue
   else:
       break
```

This will send a message once per two seconds since we set the timeout to 2. which is well below the rate limit but still breaks the ToS

### References:

- [`asyncio.TimeoutError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-exceptions.html#asyncio.TimeoutError) - you have to import it with `import asyncio`
- [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for)
- [Read the Terms of Services](https://discord.com/terms)